# Convert CRON expressions to RRULE

Tags: cron, icalendar, rrule

I'm working on a backend where we're using CRON expressions to find future occurrences. Now they want to replace CRON with RRULE for more flexible expressions. The problem is, we've got hundreds of CRON expressions that now need to be converted into RRULE expressions.

I can't seem to find any information about this online. All I can find is about converting RRULE into CRON expressions...

Anyone got any advice?